Can I make this template choose the right overloaded function?
I have some C++ code that uses templates to create function wrappers around member functions. Here is a link to code on the compiler explorer, and here is the same code below. It's a simplification of some real-world code in which the wrappers are more complicated.
The templates setter_fn or getter_fn take a pointer to member function, and produce a top-level function with a signature, PrimImplFun, aka Obj* (*)(const vector<FunArg> &args). (This dynamically typed signature is made for a scripting language.)
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct Obj {};
struct FunArg {
    string kw;
    Obj *val;
};
using PrimImplFun = Obj*(*)(const vector<FunArg> &args);

struct Foo : public Obj {};
class Device : public Obj {
    Foo *m_foo;
public:
    Foo *foo() { 
        cout << "in foo()\n";
        return m_foo; 
    }
    Foo *get_foo() { return foo(); }
    void foo(Foo *f) { 
        cout << "in foo(Foo*)\n";
        m_foo = f; 
    }
    void set_foo(Foo *f) { foo(f); }
};

// Wrapper templates

template<typename T> struct member_pointer_class;

template<typename Class, typename Value>
struct member_pointer_class<Value Class::*> {
    using type = Class;
};

template<typename T> struct member_pointer_arg0;

template<typename Class, typename Value, typename A0>
struct member_pointer_arg0<Value (Class::*)(A0)> {
    using type = A0;
};

template<typename>
constexpr bool is_one_arg_void_ret_member_function{};

template<typename Klass, typename A0>
constexpr bool is_one_arg_void_ret_member_function<void (Klass::*)(A0 a)> = true;

template <auto memfun> 
Obj *getter_fn(const vector<FunArg> &args) {
    using T = member_pointer_class<decltype(memfun)>::type;
    T *obj = (T*)args[0].val;
    auto res = (obj->*memfun)();
    return res;
}
template <auto memfun>  
requires is_one_arg_void_ret_member_function<decltype(memfun)>
Obj *setter_fn(const vector<FunArg> &args) {
    using T = member_pointer_class<decltype(memfun)>::type;
    using A0 = member_pointer_arg0<decltype(memfun)>::type;
    T *obj = (T*)args[0].val;
    A0 a0 = (A0)args[1].val;
    (obj->*memfun)(a0);
    return nullptr;
}

// End Wrapper templates

struct Prop {
    string name;
    PrimImplFun getter;
    PrimImplFun setter;
};

Prop the_prop;

void make_prop(string name, PrimImplFun getter, PrimImplFun setter) { 
    the_prop = { name, getter, setter };
}

int main() {
    // This line works. The templates create the top-level functions that wrap the member functions.
    // make_prop("foo", getter_fn<&Device::get_foo>, setter_fn<&Device::set_foo>);   
    
    // This doesn't work, because `Device::foo` is overloaded. Is there a way to make the template pick 
    // the `foo(Foo*)` overload?
    make_prop("foo", getter_fn<&Device::get_foo>, setter_fn<&Device::foo>);   

    Device dev;
    Foo foo;
    vector<FunArg> args = {{"", &dev}, {"", &foo}};
    the_prop.setter(args);
    the_prop.getter(args);
    cout << "Done.\n";
}

It works if I don't have overloads, and the functions are called get_foo() and set_foo(Foo*), but I'd to know if there is a way to get it to work when the getter and setter member functions are foo() and foo(Foo*). In that case the error from MSVC is (not very helpful):
1>C:\main.cc(95,5): error C2664: 'void make_prop(std::string,PrimImplFun,PrimImplFun)':
      cannot convert argument 3 
      from 'Obj *(__cdecl *)(const std::vector<FunArg,std::allocator<FunArg>> &)' 
      to 'PrimImplFun'
1>    C:\main.cc(95,51):
1>    None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
1>    C:\main.cc(85,6):
1>    see declaration of 'make_prop'
1>    C:\main.cc(95,5):
1>    while trying to match the argument list '(const char [4], overloaded-function, overloaded-function)'

My goal is to be able to create the wrapper fun in one expression, as I do with setter_fn<&Class::memfun>. But I need some way to tell it which overload to pick. Is there a way to do that? I should add: I'm aware I can use a static_cast<void (Device::*)(Foo*)>(...) to select an overload, but I'm wondering if I can make something that looks nicer, where the cast is not right there everytime I use setter_fn to create a wrapper.
As you can see on the setter_fn template I tried to use a requires clause to narrow it to only look at foo(Foo*), not foo(), but that doesn't appear to work.

"Is there a way to make the template pick  the foo(Foo*) overload?" no, you have to be explicit about it. Hint: don't use the same name for getters and setters.

Better still, don't have getters and setters. A class should do stuff, not have stuff.
